# Deleting null character from a file

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, fseek, fgetc

When writing in a file, I generate several null characters /00 each time a new write operation is performed. Bellow it is my approach to tackle this task, but it does not work.

File content:

foo\00\00\00\00\00\00

Code approach:

```
int aux;
while((aux = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
    printf("%i\n", aux);
    if(fgetc(fp) == '\00'){
        fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_SET);
        ftruncate(fileno(fp), ftell(fp)); 
    }
}
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter to `fseek()` is the position to seek to, either relative or absolute, based on the 3rd parameter. The `SEEK_SET` value says you're seeking to an absolute position of `-1`, which I suspect fails with an error. You probably meant to use `SEEK_CUR`, making the 2nd parameter an offset from the current position. Checking the return of `fseek()` would be appropriate.

That said, I would instead maintain my own count as I iterated through the file and truncate based on that count, removing the need for `fseek()` and `ftell()`. (Well, that's assuming I couldn't just eliminate the writing of NULL's in the first place -- that would be the proper course to take if possible).

Comment: The problem is that the file is quite long and the insertions are done constantly. Therefore, if it has to iterate over the whole file every time a new insertion is made, it will lose a lot of time

Comment: Can you not just eliminate the NULL's at the time of insertion? Look at the data prior to calling `fwrite()` (or whatever method you write with) and adjust the size accordingly? That will certainly take less time then looking at the file contents after every write, and if your data has NULL values in the middle of valid content currently, you're really creating much more work for yourself than a simple `ftruncate()` solves.

Comment: Yes, but even though the way I say it is not the handiest way for this example, I am curious about knowing also this way (iterating over the file).